# Mongoose don't save new document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save a mongodb document in my node server by mongoose :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/appJobs');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function() {console.log("error")});
db.once('open', function () {
console.log("connected!");
// init the schema 
var jobSchema = mongoose.Schema({ bName: String , phone :Number ,location:[{longitude:Number,latitude:Number}],Email:String,field:String,exp:String});
var job = mongoose.model('jobs',jobSchema);
```

And my job data should come from that POST request :

```
app.get('/postJob', function(req,res){
    console.log("request method :" + req.method);
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8020');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // Pass to next layer 

    console.log("Data :");
    var postObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    //testing
    console.log(postObject);
    console.log(postObject.bname);

    // creating and saving the posted job data to mongodb\jobs

    var recJob = new job ({'bName':postObject.bname , 'phone' : postObject.bPhone ,'Email':postObject.bEmail ,'field':postObject.fieldSelected});
        recJob.save(function(error,prod) {
    if(error) {
    console.log("error");
            }
    else {
        console.log("a job was saved to mongodb");

        }
});
    res.send("OK!");


});
```

The error i get is : "ReferenceError: job is not defined " although i defined at befor the server started .  the postObject is the source of the data i want to add .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from your post if you are closing out the db.once callback before you are defining the app.get route.  The `jobs` variable is scoped at the anonymous function for the `db.once` callback.

Mongoose if very good about letting you break up your model definition into multiple files.  Once you connect mongoose in your server bootstrapper, it's global and you can put your model definitions in their own file.